# Dividing a string into all possible 4-letter consequent phrases

Tags: java, arrays, string

What I'm trying to do is basically this:

1. Read a file;
2. Remove all punctuation and convert all letters to lowercase;
3. Convert words to 4 letter phrases (if the word is shorter than 4 characters, take it as a whole);

Example:

> Input: Hello, my identification is Mister Dude.
>
> Output: hell, ello, my, iden, dent, enti, ntif, tifi, ific, fica, icat, cati, atio, tion, is, mist, iste, ster, dude.

It would be nice if I could get each 4-word phrase as a separate value in an array.

Now the things I've managed to complete:

```
public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);
    int numberOfLines = readLines();
    String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
        textData[i] = textReader.readLine();
        textData[i] = textData[i].replaceAll("[^A-Za-ząčęėįšųūž]+", " ").toLowerCase();
    }
    textReader.close();

    return textData;
}
```

The `textData[i]` is each line of text which I need to divide.
I've tried several methods, such as `.toCharArray` and 2D arrays but I can't seem to manage the letter arrangement part. How can I complete task no.3?

Comment: Have you considered using a ring buffer with 4 elements?http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

Comment: how come `my` and `is`  (2 letter words) are in the output?

Comment: @MaxZoom  (if the word is shorter than 4 characters, take it as a whole)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/U54a49):

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String text = "Hello, my identification is Mister Dude.";
    String[] words = text.replaceAll("[^(\\w )]+", "").toLowerCase().split(" ");
    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.length() <= 4) {
            System.out.println(word);
        } 
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i <= word.length() - 4; i++) {
                System.out.println(word.substring(i, i + 4));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing the requirement on the lowercase stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, for each word, you need to iterate over the possible positions to start a four letter sequence from:

```
public static List<String> sequences (String line) {
    List result = new LinkedList<>();
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.length() <= 4) {
            result.add(word);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i <= word.length() - 4; ++i) {
                result.add(word.substring(i, i + 4));
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Small fixes: `i <= word.length() - 4` and `result.add(word.substring(i, i + 4))`.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk right, on both issues. Edited my answer to fix them both. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: This has an issue and is that it includes the punctuation signs, that are not required in the question. The second issue is: if it has a double space, it generate an unwanted output.

Answer (score 1):

Kick-off example:

```
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < textData.length; i++) {
        String[] currLine = textData[i].split("\\s+");
        for (String word : currLine) {
            if (word.length() > 4) {
                for (int j = 0; j < currLine.length - 4; j++) {
                    result.add(word.substring(j, j + 4));
                }
            } else {
                result.add(word);
            }
        }
    }
```

I didn't test it, so please, check and let me know if it works.

Comment: It doesn't, but very close :) Interestingly enough, 3 out of 4 answerers (including me) initially made the same off-by-one error.

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to split your methods by space and punctuation signs. Please note the split in the 3rd line, that is splitting by any combination of spaces and punctuation signs.

In my example I had

```
    String text = "Hello, my identification is Mister Dude.";

    String[] textArray = text.split("\\W+");
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String word : textArray) {
        result.addAll(Arrays.asList(split(word.toLowerCase(), 4)));
    }
```

and then the method

```
private static String[] split(String word, int letters) {
    if (word == null || word.length() == 0) {
        return new String[] {};
    } else if (word.length() <= letters) {
        return new String[] { word };
    } else {
        int quantity = (word.length() - letters) + 1;
        String[] val = new String[quantity];
        int a = 0;
        while (a + letters <= word.length()) {
            val[a] = word.substring(a, a + letters);
            a++;
        }
        return val;
    }
}
```

This outputs the following

```
[hell, ello, my, iden, dent, enti, ntif, tifi, ific, fica, icat, cati, atio, tion, is, mist, iste, ster, dude]
```